# UILabel in drawRect does not draw

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uilabel

quick question, I got this `drawRect` method in the a `UIView` with a `UILabel` and circle.The circle is drawn correctly but the `UILabel` is not.

Any ideas?

Thanks your help.

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)theRect{

    CGRect rect = self.bounds;


    //text label
    UILabel * pText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: rect];
    pText.text = @"demo";

    // Circle
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect];
    rect = CGRectInset(rect, 5, 5);
    [path appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect]];
    path.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;
    [self.color set];
    [path fill];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your UILabel to your view.

```
//text label
UILabel * pText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: rect];
pText.text = @"demo";
[self addSubview:pText];
[pText release];
```

Comment: this, but don't do this in `drawRect`, but in a place where it is done once. `drawRect` might be called more than once.

Comment: Thx guys that was quick! Do I need to add UILabel because it is a view object and not rect as UIBezierPath is contains the draw instructions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call :

```
[super drawRect:rect];
```

in order to draw your uilabel before drawing the circle.